# Find largest difference between adjacent floats in ordered array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Say I have an *ordered* array/list like this one:

```
a = [0.2, 0.35, 0.88, 1.2, 1.33, 1.87, 2.64, 2.71, 3.02]
```

I want to find the largest difference between adjacent elements efficiently. In this case it would be `(2.64 - 1.87) = 0.77`.

I could use a `for` loop but I wonder if there's a more elegant/efficient solution. Solutions using `numpy` are welcomed.

---

**TEST**

OK, I took all the answers and tested them (see code at the bottom). These are the results in seconds:

```
0.0867638587952 0.118239144757 mark
0.00386190414429 0.118239144757 Padraic
0.00108003616333 0.118239144757 mtrw
0.0790281295776 0.118239144757 yurib
0.000712156295776 0.118239144757 elyase
```

which means *elyase* is the winner by several orders of magnitude. Thank you all!

---

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0., 1000., 100000))

tik = time.time()
val = max(y - x for x,y in zip(a, a[1:]))
print time.time() - tik, val, 'mark'

tik = time.time()
val = np.ediff1d(a).max()
print time.time() - tik, val, 'Padraic'

tik = time.time()
val = np.max(np.abs(np.diff(a)))
print time.time() - tik, val, 'mtrw'

tik = time.time()
val = max(a[i+1]-a[i] for i in range(len(a)-1))
print time.time() - tik, val, 'yurib'

tik = time.time()
val = np.diff(a).max()
print time.time() - tik, val, 'elyase'
```

Comment: `time.time()` is a horrible way of doing code timing, that's why Python includes `timeit`.  I'm not just saying that because I came in last, I kind of expected my method wouldn't be efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A numpy solution:

```
np.diff(a).max()
```

Comment: Fastest solution. Also very succinct and elegant.

Answer (score 4):

I can't claim it's more efficient or more elegant, but it's different:

```
>>> max(y - x for x,y in zip(a, a[1:]))
0.77
```

Comment: I see you are living by the statement _Think different_ :D

Answer (score 2):

```
max(a[i+1]-a[i] for i in range(len(a)-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want to get a little crazy about performance, we can use `numba`:

```
import numba

@autojit
def max_consecutive_diff(x):
    prev = x[0]
    diff_max = 0.0

    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        cur = x[i]
        diff = cur - prev

        if diff > diff_max:
            diff_max = diff

        prev = cur

    return diff_max
```

Here's a speed test. Generating data with

```
>>> x = np.sort(np.random.sample(1e7))
```

we get:

```
>>> %timeit max_consecutive_diff(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.9 ms per loop

>>> %timeit np.max(np.diff(x))
10 loops, best of 3: 33.9 ms per loop
```

Of course, these are *milliseconds* for ten-million long input array. I'd just stick with the `np.diff` solution, but it's always cool to see how well `numba` can do.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [0.2, 0.35, 0.88, 1.2, 1.33, 1.87, 2.64, 2.71, 3.02]

import numpy as np
print(np.ediff1d(a).max())
0.77
```

Difference between `diff` and `ediff1d` is ediff1d will flatten before comparing:

```
In [18]: y = [[1, 2, 4], [1, 6, 24]]

In [19]: print(np.ediff1d(y))
[ 1  2 -3  5 18]

In [20]: print(np.diff(y))
[[ 1  2]
 [ 5 18]]
```

Comment: @Veedrac, it flattens the array if necessary

Comment: (The question was "What's the difference between `ediff1d` and `diff`?"; I deleted the question just before it was answered.) Thanks.